# Sending sign up data from user to server

Tags: java, android, database, http

EDIT:
I finally figured out where the problem is. I keep getting an IOException on this line
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost).

However, the normal problems that will cause this error (the ones that I searched online, like the url being wrong and such) are not the problem here. The url is correct. Can anyone help or list all of the possible reasons I would get this error. Thank you.

---

I know this question has been asked several times, and I actually looked at the answers given for those questions in order to originally figure out how to do this but for some reason it's not working and I don't know why.

I have an app that requires a user to sign up. After they sign up I send the information they inputted to the server.

Android code:

```
//This is the method called when user presses submit button. The variables not declared
//are global
public void registerUser(View v){
    context = getApplicationContext();

    username = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
    email = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
    password=((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

    String[] params = {username,email,password};
    (new SendRegisterInfo(this.getApplicationContext())).execute(params);

    Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "Thank you for Signing up "+username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
    //Start Main Page Activity. Page they'll see everytime they login
    Intent i = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}


public class SendRegisterInfo extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

private String tag = "SendRegisterInfo";
private InputStream is;
private Context c;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

public SendRegisterInfo(Context c){
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String URI="http://www.mysite.com/registerUser.php";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URI);
    HttpResponse response;

    String username,email,password;
    username = params[0];
    email = params[1];
    password = params[2];


    try {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> submit = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        submit.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
        submit.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
        submit.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(submit));

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.i(tag,response.getStatusLine().toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(tag, "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


}
```

Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$username =  $_POST["username"];
$email =  $_POST["email"];
$pswrd = $_POST["password"];
$score = 0;

$user = "root";
$password="pword";
$database = "databasename";

mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to Select Database");

$query="INSERT INTO Players VALUES ('','$username','$email','$pswrd','','$score')";

mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: You say it is working and you don't know why?

Comment: what is not working? Try to debug your code..does the php script work if you create a simple form and post the data? Does Android actually send the content? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The only issue I see by quickly looking at the code is that you do network activity on the UI thread (unless you didn't post the entire code).

Comment: @YuviDroid I put this here in the comments instead of the question b/c I don't want it to get cluttered. I did what you suggested, doing the network activity on another thread but not only did it not submit the info but it also crashed the app. I've included the code I modified at the end of the question.

Comment: Take a look at the logs (LogCat) to see why it crashed so you can fix that. As a side note: to run stuff in the background I usually use an AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a Service.

Comment: What's the response value?  Perhaps you can edit your PHP to output the results.

Comment: Your code is open for SQL injections! It is really simple to drop your database. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error reading the (String... params) argument of the doInBackground() method.

When you start the AsyncTask:

```
 String[] params = {username,email,password};
```

When you read the arguments

```
String username,email,weight,password;
username = params[0];
email = params[1];
password = params[3];  // should be: password = params[2];
```

If this isn't works, adds a mySql query asking for the last insert id on the php program and print the result to get the response in the client:

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();    
Log.i(tag,EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString());
```

So you can see if you are inserting or not on the db.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The errors you first listed were actually typos on my part. I also located where the error is actually and edited the question again.

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue:

```
RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

You're attempting to show a Toast from a class that isn't designed to show a Toast.  Or, perhaps, isn't prepared to show a tost.  What is the class containing the method `registerUser`

Comment: Thank you for your response and that was actually one of the errors. I fixed it and the app stopped crashing, but the data is still not being sent over to the server. Apparently the major problem is with this line response = httpClient.execute(httpPost), giving me an IOException. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below.

- Add function name and key to the request along with your data.

  ```
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3); 

  nameValuePairs.add((NameValuePair) new BasicNameValuePair("f", "yourFunctionName."+methodName));

  nameValuePairs.add((NameValuePair) new BasicNameValuePair("u", "a0ff8a6a0a831ec25cf4de6c730be54c"));

  //u is the key used by server to identify valid request.
  ```